# I can't submit question. How can I send it?

Tags: support

I'm an EL&U user. I kept posting Q&As for past 10 months without problem. When I was trying to post a question yesterday, a message saying “Your question couldn't be submitted because name and email are missing,” and the boxes to input my name and email address were shown below the question box. I saw this massage for the first time since I started posting question.

I entered both and clicked. Then the message, “Your question not submitted because your email is already registered” appeared. It was followed by the request for encoding funny letters, all resulting in vain.

Since every time I try to post a question, the question box is persistently occupied by the old text I tried to submit yesterday, and I can submit neither that question nor new questions. I want to send the question, or erase it thoroughly for entering a new question.

How can I solve the problem? Is it better to get a new account?

Comment: Have you tried logging out and logging back in?

Comment: @Martha. No, I'm a complete internet illiterate. I even don't know What logging out / logging back in mreans and how to do it.

Comment: @Martha. Hoever, the page recovered by itself for unknown reason. The question I input the day before yesterday remained unsubmitted and kept demanding me to input registered or new address and code has gone and was put in place, when I opened my page the next morning. I don't still know why the problem happened and why it was resolved without making any effective actions. Anyway, thank for your attention. I was able to come back to the forum.

Answer (score 7):

If the Ask a Question page is asking for your name and email, it means that you are not logged in on that page, so it is asking for your information to post as an unregistered user.

When you put in your email there and it tells you you're already registered, it means that it knows you have an account and it wants you to login.

Please ensure that you are properly logged in (do you see your name at the top of the page is a good test) before asking your question and you shouldn't have any issues.